# How do write my own version of multisig

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature

I was wondering if someone could help me out with something.

For fun I'm trying to get mulsig working in my own react app.  Where I'm stuck is this.  I use the sdk to create a transaction and sign it, but I don't understand what to do next.

I want to switch to another user and sign and send that transaction.  What I don't understand is the following

1. What exactly is the safe transaction hash and what do I need it for?
2. What exactly does the format look like for my final transaction? Do I need that safe transaction hash? do I need the previous signature or is that in the safe transaction hash?  Is there an abi I need to be using?

I've tried looking through some exist repos, but none of them go to this depth.  They leverage loading their app as a module, which is cool but I want to do my own version for fun. I also looked in the app and I can't find in super in depth documentation on this.  I also tried to find a white paper for how the safe works exactly and I couldn't find anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: Do you mean to create a smart contract that handles multi-signature logic? Signing a transaction would simply be called a "sign" function in the smart contract to let it know that you are "signing" x transaction. And when it's fully signed by m out of n signers, then it can be broadcasted. Let me know if you are referring to this to write an example smart contract.

Comment: as Jeremy said. + this video might be worth a look
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ja72g_Dac4